# How to bind set object to controller in spring

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to make a post call to a controller, but the object I am expecting contains a Set datatype and I am unsure how the post data should look.

Models:

```
public class Notebook{
  private string name;
  private Set<Todo> todos;
}

public class Todo{
  private String name;
}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void createNotebook(Notebook q){
    questionnaireService.saveOrUpdateNotebook(q);
}
```

Currently I have tried posting like the example below:

```
curl --data "name=some notebook&todos[0].name=todo1&todos[1].name=todo2" http://localhost:8080/api/notebook
```

Doesn't seem to work. Anyone have experience with Sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should qualify `Notebook q` with `@RequestBody` annotation so that the request can be mapped to an object of type `Notebook`. More about the format of the input data and the converters in Spring MVC doc: [Mapping the request body with the @RequestBody annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody).

We send data from the front-end in JSON format and use Jackson JSON to convert it to the Java object. If you go that route, you can directly declare the `todos` as `Set<String>` and the input would be

```
{
    name: "some notebook",
    todos: ["todo1", "todo2"]
}
```

Comment: thanks. I could also change the datatype from Set to List and use the array index I wanted to use before.